# Como fazer um intervalo de predição para um grupo restrito?

Tags: r

Considerando o modelo com apenas estas duas variáveis explicativas,
indique um **intervalo de predição a 95% para um individuo no
primeiro quartil (1st Qu) de X1 e da segunda categoria de X2**.

Sei o código genérico, mas ñ consigo restringir para o grupo pedido, o código que usei:`pr.p <- predict(model,interval="prediction",level=0.95)`

Ex do banco:

```html
glucose insulin FIDADE
89 94 1
78 88 1
118 230 1
126 235 1
97 140 1
158 245 1
88 54 1
145 130 2
126 22 2
187 392 2
130 79 2
187 200 2
128 110 2
166 175 3
143 146 3
150 342 3
136 110 3
134 60 4
173 265 4
195 145 4
145 165 4
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para prever usando o modelo ajustado com `lm`, tem de ter um dataframe com as variáveis regressoras nos pontos que quer. O código abaixo cria um sub-df com as linhas em que `insulin` está no 1º quartil e `FIDADE` é da categoria `2`.

Supondo que o modelo ajustado é este:

```
model <- lm(glucose ~ insulin + FIDADE, data = dados)
```

Pode-se obter um intervalo de predição com:

```
qq <- quantile(dados$insulin, probs = 0.25)
i1 <- with(dados, qq >= insulin)
i2 <- with(dados, FIDADE == 2)
new <- dados[i1 & i2, c("insulin", "FIDADE")]
predict(model, newdata = new, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)
#        fit     lwr      upr
#9  108.6813 60.2474 157.1153
#11 118.9752 72.0415 165.9090
```

**Edição.**

Atendendo ao pedido no comentário para simular o aumento em 20% da amplitude da variável insulina, o único problema parece ser a criação de um conjunto de dados com amplitude de insulina 20% maior em cada categoria. (Pelo menos é o que penso fazer mais sentido.)

```
rng <- with(dados, tapply(insulin, FIDADE, FUN = range))
rng <- lapply(rng, function(r){
  d <- diff(r)
  c(max(r) - 1.1*d, min(r + 1.1*d))
})
tmp <- unlist(lapply(names(rng), function(n) rep(as.integer(n), length(rng[[n]]))))
nova_ampl <- data.frame(insulin = unlist(rng), FIDADE = tmp)
rm(rng, tmp)
```

Agora é só passar este dataframe no argumento `newdata`.

```
predict(model, newdata = nova_ampl, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)
#         fit       lwr      upr
#11  94.76547  45.69869 143.8323
#12 136.15787  87.45688 184.8589
#21 101.99931  52.22080 151.7778
#22 182.18353 128.06123 236.3058
#31 136.62942  89.30538 183.9535
#32 186.90710 135.84374 237.9705
#41 144.33280  93.69015 194.9755
#42 188.75920 138.68448 238.8339
```

**Dados em formato `dput`.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(glucose = c(89L, 78L, 118L, 126L, 97L, 
158L, 88L, 145L, 126L, 187L, 130L, 187L, 128L, 166L, 
143L, 150L, 136L, 134L, 173L, 195L, 145L), 
insulin = c(94L, 88L, 230L, 235L, 140L, 245L, 
54L, 130L, 22L, 392L, 79L, 200L, 110L, 175L, 146L, 
342L, 110L, 60L, 265L, 145L, 165L), 
FIDADE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: Muito muito obrigado Rui Barradas!! vc resolveu o meu problema!!

Comment: Rui Barradas aproveitando a sua ajuda vc saberia me dizer como simular o aumento em 20% da variável insulina?
 A pergunta segue abaixo... 
**Interprete o efeito provocado por um aumento em X1 correspondente
a 20% da amplitude dos seus valores**

Eu sou bem iniciante em R.. na verdade nunca trabalhei com o soft e por causa de uma cadeira do mestrdo tenho que fazer esses exercicios.

Comment: @GabrielCostaPinto Feito, veja a edição.

Comment: Mais uma vez um muito muito obrigado!! @RuiBarradas